# Return coordinates with in a radius of initial Lat and Long

Tags: r

Currently I am in school project and I am quite new to R and the forums and scripting in general

I have `Lat_X` and `Long_Y`.

I also have a table that contains a list of `Lat_n` and `Long_n`.

How can I return all values from the table that are within 100 km from the `Lat_X` and `Long_Y` coordinate?

Comment: Have a look at the distance functions in the `geosphere` library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `gBuffer` function from `rgeos` package in order to create circles. Be aware that you have to use some planar projection for this.

Then you can "subset" points with `over` function.

Example:

```
library(sp)
library(rgeos)

# Initial data
lat_X = 10
long_Y = 10
Radius = 500000 # in meters
Points_dat <- data.frame(lon_n = c(8:15), lat_n = c(8:15))

### Solution with SP and rgeos packages

# First, prepare projected spatial objects
Origin <- SpatialPoints(data.frame(long_Y, lat_X),
                    proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

Points <- SpatialPoints(Points_dat, proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))

# Reproject them into planar
Origin_t <- spTransform(Origin, CRS("+init=epsg:2393"))
Points_t <- spTransform(Points, CRS("+init=epsg:2393"))

# Construct buffer
Circle <- gBuffer(Origin_t, width=Radius, byid=TRUE)

# Plot_results
plot(Circle)
plot(Points_t, add=TRUE)
plot(Origin_t, add=TRUE, pch=16)
plot(Points_t[!is.na(over(Points_t, Circle)), ], pch=5, col=2, add=TRUE)


# Make subset
Points_subset <- Points_dat[!is.na(over(Points_t, Circle)), ]
Points_subset
```

Results:

```
  lon_n lat_n
1     8     8
2     9     9
3    10    10
4    11    11
5    12    12
6    13    13
```

[image]

**UPD: Solution with geosphere**
Initial data is the same as in the previous example.

```
library(geosphere)
# Distances calculation
distances <- distm(Points_dat, c(long_Y, lat_X), fun=distHaversine)
Points_subset_1 <- Points_dat[distances <= Radius,]
# Attach column with distances in meters
Points_subset_1$dist <- distances[distances <= Radius]
Points_subset_1

  lon_n lat_n     dist
1     8     8 312918.2
2     9     9 156352.6
3    10    10      0.0
4    11    11 156115.9
5    12    12 311971.1
6    13    13 467541.5
```

The solution with `geosphere` is more appropriate if you need actual distances. Still, sometimes it is better to use buffers, for example, if you work with rasters.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I get the following error:  Error in .local(obj, ...) : 
  cannot derive coordinates from non-numeric matrix. Could it be that my values are not integer?

Comment: Can you show the structure of your objects with coordinates `str(Your_table)`?

Comment: Lat | Long
------ | ------
48.8851   | 12.519600

Comment: Is it output from `str` function?

Comment: $ Lat          : num  48.9 50.4 48.2 48.1 49.8 ...
 $ Long          : num  12.52 2.99 2.69 2.34 3.61 ...

Comment: It looks like you have a data frame with et least 7 columns. Am I right? In this case create a table with only two columns, i.e. `Points_dat <- Your_table[, c("V6", "V7")]`

Comment: Alright, can you edit your question and add names of your variables and full outputs from`str` functions for them?

Comment: Update: I just realized that the values from the initial coordinates were factors not numeric. Thanks.

Comment: But `str` says that you have numerical values (': num' in output).

Comment: sorry for not being clear. The initial value are also read from another table. the idea is to crete a loop and go through all the values for the initial table.

Comment: I am getting the following error  for the following data non finite transformation detected:
    lat_X    long_Y                     
  42.5339 -114.3740       Inf       Inf  Error in spTransform(Origin, CRS("+init=epsg:2393")) : 
  failure in points 1 In addition: Warning message:
In spTransform(Origin, CRS("+init=epsg:2393")) :
  1 projected point(s) not finite

Comment: Sorry, think I missed something. You need longitude, latitude order, i.e.  long_X lat_Y -114.3740 42.5339

Comment: Thanks for the order, but right now this is secondary priorioty. Could it be possible to get only the coordinate with the minimum distance and the distance in metters?

Comment: I have updated my answer. The solution with `geosphere` is more appropriate if you need actual distances. Still, sometimes it is better to use buffers, for example, if you work with rasters.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So i can actually see the min distance only of the points with in the buffer. I think this would be a little more efficent or?

Comment: Variable `distances` contains distances for all points. You can  attach it to the initial table with points: `Points_dat$dist <- distances`

Comment: Plese, don't forget to accept my answer if it was helpful for you.